# How to calculate R, S, and Z from raw bitcoin transaction with witness?

Tags: signature, raw-transaction, python, nodejs

How can I calculate the R, S, and Z values from a raw bitcoin transaction? I can extract them with `rscan.py`, but that doesn't work for new transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in [BIP-141](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki), the witness for a P2WPKH spend is as follows:

> The witness must consist of exactly 2 items (≤ 520 bytes each). The first one a signature, and the second one a public key.

The signature consists of the usual R and s values that you're looking for, as before.

---

Let's look at [this transaction](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/9ae7ce79fa8501dd92ade347fae7c1737ccefa6db204a2fae485634c265d5494) you keep linking to. Let's look at the first input.

We can see the scriptPubKey is

```
OP_HASH160 fcebfb01198e90e99875a913dd592650fd2df667 OP_EQUAL
```

This means it is a P2SH spend, where the P2SH redeem script has the hash `fcebfb0....67`

Let's look at that redeem script then:

```
0020d687015ac2304c3213491ff4fc71ea15e9c170fddedd8bed92be2d191f8adddd
```

This is OP_0 followed by a push of 32-bytes. That means it's a P2WSH spend. Because this was wrapped inside P2SH, it's called P2SH-P2WSH. But there is no public key or signature involved so far, just scripts.

The witness consists of three pushes onto the stack. This includes the witness script:

```
OP_PUSHNUM_2 OP_PUSHBYTES_33 035e1822f3a6eec3911545188bb0e6df3826eef8b630a77d1e344ba5954d9534a8 OP_PUSHBYTES_33 03694100a1f02854db3acac05c878053aba59fedfe3ebb1b7e094051aa61da6ba8 OP_PUSHBYTES_33 03e9509f6b6ad39542aa816c24d50d8ca7d83cfa6b430f0c366184957961a07fd6 OP_PUSHNUM_3 OP_CHECKMULTISIG
```

In other words, this is a 2-of-3 multisig. The other two items on the witness stack are therefore signatures. But this is going to be different for every possible type of script, so there isn't going to be a way to just "extract" the signature from P2WSH spends. Best to focus just on the key-based spends.

Comment: please see this it has long witness ,https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/9ae7ce79fa8501dd92ade347fae7c1737ccefa6db204a2fae485634c265d5494

Comment: That's because that transaction is a P2SH-P2WSH transaction, meaning a script is used rather than a key and signature.

Comment: Extract what? Just use the same logic as rscan.py that you mentioned, but look at the witness field as I described.

Comment: Which TX? The P2WSH one? I told you, it is a script spend, not a key + signature spend.

Comment: https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/9ae7ce79fa8501dd92ade347fae7c1737ccefa6db204a2fae485634c265d5494

Comment: Yes, that's a P2SH-P2SWH transaction. I already told you that. It isn't a key + signature transaction (P2WPKH). I've added an explanation to my answer.